# Python 3 pandas .sort() does not work on object column generated by df.dtypes

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, types

I have a dataframe `df` that has some `float`, `int` and `datetime` columns. I want an other dataframe `res` that should have only one column that's value is `df.dtypes`. And I want to sort this `res` dataframe but I get wrong results in Python 3.4.3 (pandas 0.16.2). My code is:

```
data=[dt.datetime.strptime('16Sep2012','%d%b%Y'),11,12.2,22\
    ,dt.datetime.strptime('16Sep2013','%d%b%Y'),22.2,33\
    ,dt.datetime.strptime('16Sep2014','%d%b%Y')\
    ,dt.datetime.strptime('16Sep2015','%d%b%Y'),33.2]

df=pd.DataFrame([data]*10)
res=pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes,columns=['type'])

res
             type
0  datetime64[ns]
1           int64
2         float64
3           int64
4  datetime64[ns]
5         float64
6           int64
7  datetime64[ns]
8  datetime64[ns]
9         float64

res.sort('type')
             type
1           int64
4  datetime64[ns]
3           int64
6           int64
5         float64
2         float64
0  datetime64[ns]
7  datetime64[ns]
8  datetime64[ns]
9         float64
```

If I generate `res2` "manually" with strings than sorting works perfectly:

```
strings=['datetime64[ns]','int64','float64','int64'\
    ,'datetime64[ns]','float64','int64','datetime64[ns]'\
    ,'datetime64[ns]','float64']

res2=pd.DataFrame(strings,columns=['type'])

res2
             type
0  datetime64[ns]
1           int64
2         float64
3           int64
4  datetime64[ns]
5         float64
6           int64
7  datetime64[ns]
8  datetime64[ns]
9         float64

res2.sort('type')
             type
8  datetime64[ns]
4  datetime64[ns]
7  datetime64[ns]
0  datetime64[ns]
2         float64
5         float64
9         float64
1           int64
3           int64
6           int64
```

Is there a bug or what did I wrong? How can I sort this correctly?
In Python 2.7.10 (pandas 0.16.2), sorting `res` gives this result (of course sorting `res2` works perfectly):

```
res.sort('type')
             type
1           int64
3           int64
6           int64
2         float64
5         float64
9         float64
7  datetime64[ns]
8  datetime64[ns]
0  datetime64[ns]
4  datetime64[ns]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also with Python 2.1.10 and pandas 0.16.2, and sorting `res` works, but sorting it gives me *exactly what you got from sorting `res2`* ("datetime64"s coming before "float64", before "int64"); and not the reversed (int to float to datetime) order that you describe in the last part of the question

Comment: Correction: it actually gives me datetimes first; then int64 and lastly float64!

Comment: you are doing a sort of numpy dtype objects, that is very odd to do. what is your goal here?

Comment: I'm trying to enhance `pd.DataFrame.describe()` to result dtypes, number of unique and NULL values, value counts with a limit (and all of these for dates as well)... and I want to sort the result by index and by dtypes. `res.dtypes` gives `object` for `type`...